# Returning the name of a category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a loop for a custom post type an all is working well, except I cannot return the actual category name that the post has assigned to it.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
  $posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
  ));


  if($posts) {
    foreach($posts as $post) {
      setup_postdata( $post );
      ?>
      <div>
        <div class="mix <?php get_cat_name( ); ?>" ><img src="<?php the_field('portfolio_image'); ?>" alt=""></div> <!-- ACF -->
      </div>
      <?php
    }
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

This is just one of the WP Codex functions I have tried including tring all with echo. I imagine my problem is something else?
Many thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the codex an id is *required* for this method (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_name). Leaving out the id will not work.

One solution would be to use `get_the_category($postId)` to retrieve the category for your post (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category). You can leave out the postId here

> post_id
>   (integer) (optional) The post id.
>   Default: $post->ID (The current post ID)

Note that the method returns an object - not the category name. You can try the following code to see if it's working:

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but second option just returns nothing

Comment: @PeteNorris: I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
     <?php $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'TAXONOMY' );
     if ($terms && ! is_wp_error($terms)) :
     $term_slugs_arr = array();
      foreach ($terms as $term) {
       $term_slugs_arr[] = $term->name;
     }
     $terms_slug_str = join( " ", $term_slugs_arr);
     endif;
     echo $terms_slug_str;?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I placed this inside the original loop (not sure if that's the right place) either way, nothing was returned.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

from

get_cat_name( );

to

```
$categories = get_the_terms($post->ID,'custom-texonomy-name');                
$cat = key($categories); 
echo $categories[$cat]->name;
```

Comment: where replace custom-texonomy-name with your register texonomy name